# Xcode 8, Swift, NSTimer not available, gives me errors when using

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im trying to use the NSTimer code within Swift and Xcode does not recognise it.

[image: (image) I have inserted NSTimer code into an Xcode playground file]

[image: (image)Xcode does not give me any related code to NSTimer as well]

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimer` has been renamed to `Timer` in Swift 3:

```
var timer = Timer()
```